# Can't bind to '*ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, filter, data-binding, pipe, ngfor

I was trying to bind value for `filter` in `*ngFor`. but it was not properly worked. How can i bind data to `ngFor`?
source code as follows,

In `.ts` file,

```
menuIcons:any[];
public pageName:any = "projects";
```

```
this.menuIcons=[{
            'id':'0',
            'name':'',
            'cat':'default'
          },
          {
            'id':'1',
            'name':'apps',
            'cat':'projects'
          }];
```

I was tried following codes, in `.html` file,

**First Attempt -->** `filter:'{{pageName}}'`

```
<div class="Container" style="position:relative" *ngFor="let icon of menuIcons | filter:'{{pageName}}' ">
 <button mat-button  class="user-button" >                 
 <mat-icon class="s-28">{{icon.name}}</mat-icon>
 </button>
</div>
```

**Second Attempt -->** `filter:'${pageName}'`

```
<div class="Container" style="position:relative" *ngFor="let icon of menuIcons | filter:'${PageName}' ">
 <button mat-button  class="user-button" >                 
 <mat-icon class="s-28">{{icon.name}}</mat-icon>
 </button>
</div>
```

vs code shows error as `Can't bind to '*ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```js
<div class="Container" style="position:relative" 
  *ngFor="let icon of menuIcons | filter:PageName">
  <button mat-button  class="user-button" >                 
  <mat-icon class="s-28">{{icon.name}}</mat-icon>
 </button>
</div>
```